# Storage and cost for a website on EC2 AWS using Node.js + express

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to understand how to use the EC2 AWS services so I've developed a dynamic website using Node.js and Express.
I'm reading the documentation but people's advice are always useful when learning new stuff.

In this website users can upload photos so I need storage space (SSD would be better).

I have three questions:

1) Is storage provided in the EC2 instance or do I have to use another AWS service as S3Bucket? What's the best/fast and less expensive solution to store and access images?

2) I'm using a t2.nano which cost $0.0063 per hour. So if i run the instance for 10 days my costs are **24hours * 10days * 0.0063**?

3)I'm using mongoDB, is a good solution to run it on my EC2 instance? Or should I use the RDS provide by AWS?

Comment: Unless your an enterprise DON'T use RDS it's stupid expensive, answer coming up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So:

1) Personally I'd use an S3 bucket to store images, note if you have multipart uploads in the S3 bucket, if one fails it'll not only not show on the object listing, it'll still use space. There's an option to remove them after a certain period.

When you add an object s3 you want to store it's key in your database, then you can simply retrieve it as required.

2) t2 nano is on free tier - so technically you can run it for nothing for the first year.

3) Personally i'd set Mongo up to run on an appropriate EC2 instance, **note**: you must properly define the Security group, you only want aws internal applications and services to access the EC2 instance, you'll need SSH access to configure it, but then I'd remove that rule from the security group.

Once your Mongo instance is setup, take an AMI so that should anything go wrong you can re deploy it configured(note this won't restore the data).

Aws pricing calc [here](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) for EC2 the easy way is to calculate it at 100% usage, the other stuff can get a bit complicated but that wizard lets you basically price up your monthly running costs.

**Edit:** checkout [this](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/ebs-efs-amazons3-best-cloud-storage-system) comparison on the different storage options for S3 vs X for storing those images although your "bible" should be that pricing calculator - I'd highly recommend learning how to use it as for your own business it's going to be invaluable and if your working for someone else it'll help you make business cases.

Comment: Thanks for you answer it is very useful :) Can I ask you some more questions? 1) about the storage space I'm reading that a solution could also be EBS, what do you think? 2) If a run mongoDB on a EC2 and something goes wrong I'll lose all my data right? What's the best approach to backup all the data? 3) The js/css files shoul should go in the EC2?

Comment: This is a discussion about EBS: [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/116011/aws-where-should-we-store-images-css-and-log-files-of-the-application)

Comment: For storage you mean for images? So as I remember EBS is about double the price, plus if you put on S3 then as your application grows you can just access the bucket rather than messing with EC2, MongoDB backup, i'd search for EBS snapshot and mongodb backup in google there's lots of articles.

Which JS/CSS are you referring to, a website?

Comment: Yes I mean the css/js files of the website. Following your advice and reading some article I was thinking: 1) S3 for images; 2) EBS for store mongoDB data. What do you think? And where should I store the css/js files of the website(EC2, S3 or EBS)?

Comment: Yep s3 for images and store the object key in your DB to retrieve it. With the website if it's just a front end application create a new S3 Bucket and set it up with Route 53, this is outside the scope of this question really, so if ya DM me on twitter(click my profile) I'm happy to assist OR ask a new question!

Comment: Ok! Thanks for your help :)